# Best effect size estimator in simple linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, effect-size

Using a metric developed by someone else, I have calculated vegetation condition scores from a set of measured variables (about 1000 sites).

I am using simple linear regression to determine how much effect each variable (covariate) has on the score (response). I have used simple sum of squares based % deviance explained (sum of squares for the term/sum of sum squares) which works well. But I am wondering if there is a better / less biased way to estimate the effect size. Someone has suggested variance ratios (mean sq of the term/residual mean sq). However, I don't understand why these would be better or if I am calculating it right? Can anyone explain to me why variance ratios would be better. Or if there is a better effect size estimator I can use in this situation? Or, is what I am doing actually fine?